# NullPointerException When trying to use Camera and setFaceDetectionListener()

Tags: java, android, android-camera, face-detection

i am trying to make an app that detects faces. The code below has no errors and from what i can see should be working fine. However when I run it, i get the following:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: org.bytefish.videofacedetection, PID: 12075
>                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.hardware.Camera.setFaceDetectionListener(android.hardware.Camera$FaceDetectionListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at org.bytefish.videofacedetection.
>   CameraActivity.surfaceCreated(CameraActivity.java:100)
>                                                                                        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:582)
>   at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2055)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

The code is below, an all caps comment shows line 100 and the error

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Face;
import android.hardware.Camera.FaceDetectionListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class CameraActivity extends Activity
        implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public static final String TAG = CameraActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Camera mCamera;

    // We need the phone orientation to correctly draw the overlay:
    private int mOrientation;
    private int mOrientationCompensation;
    private OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener;

    // Let's keep track of the display rotation and orientation also:
    private int mDisplayRotation;
    private int mDisplayOrientation;

    // Holds the Face Detection result:
    private Camera.Face[] mFaces;

    // The surface view for the camera data
    private SurfaceView mView;

    // Draw rectangles and other fancy stuff:
    private FaceOverlayView mFaceView;

    // Log all errors:
    private final CameraErrorCallback mErrorCallback = new CameraErrorCallback();


    /**
     * Sets the faces for the overlay view, so it can be updated
     * and the face overlays will be drawn again.
     */
    private FaceDetectionListener faceDetectionListener = new FaceDetectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
            Log.d("onFaceDetection", "Number of Faces:" + faces.length);
            // Update the view now!
            mFaceView.setFaces(faces);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mView = new SurfaceView(this);

        setContentView(mView);
        // Now create the OverlayView:
        mFaceView = new FaceOverlayView(this);
        addContentView(mFaceView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        // Create and Start the OrientationListener:
        mOrientationEventListener = new SimpleOrientationEventListener(this);
        mOrientationEventListener.enable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SurfaceHolder holder = mView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mOrientationEventListener.disable();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mOrientationEventListener.enable();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        mCamera = Camera.open();

        mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not preview the image.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // We have no surface, return immediately:
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Try to stop the current preview:
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore...
        }

        configureCamera(width, height);
        setDisplayOrientation();
        setErrorCallback();

        // Everything is configured! Finally start the camera preview again:
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    private void setErrorCallback() {
        mCamera.setErrorCallback(mErrorCallback);
    }

    private void setDisplayOrientation() {
        // Now set the display orientation:
        mDisplayRotation = Util.getDisplayRotation(CameraActivity.this);
        mDisplayOrientation = Util.getDisplayOrientation(mDisplayRotation, 0);

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mDisplayOrientation);

        if (mFaceView != null) {
            mFaceView.setDisplayOrientation(mDisplayOrientation);
        }
    }

    private void configureCamera(int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        // Set the PreviewSize and AutoFocus:
        setOptimalPreviewSize(parameters, width, height);
        setAutoFocus(parameters);
        // And set the parameters:
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    private void setOptimalPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters cameraParameters, int width, int height) {
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = cameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        float targetRatio = (float) width / height;
        Camera.Size previewSize = Util.getOptimalPreviewSize(this, previewSizes, targetRatio);
        cameraParameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    }

    private void setAutoFocus(Camera.Parameters cameraParameters) {
        cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(null);
        mCamera.setErrorCallback(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    /**
     * We need to react on OrientationEvents to rotate the screen and
     * update the views.
     */
    private class SimpleOrientationEventListener extends OrientationEventListener {

        public SimpleOrientationEventListener(Context context) {
            super(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            // We keep the last known orientation. So if the user first orient
            // the camera then point the camera to floor or sky, we still have
            // the correct orientation.
            if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
            mOrientation = Util.roundOrientation(orientation, mOrientation);
            // When the screen is unlocked, display rotation may change. Always
            // calculate the up-to-date orientationCompensation.
            int orientationCompensation = mOrientation
                    + Util.getDisplayRotation(CameraActivity.this);
            if (mOrientationCompensation != orientationCompensation) {
                mOrientationCompensation = orientationCompensation;
                mFaceView.setOrientation(mOrientationCompensation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to open it in android studio it opens fine with no errors but dies when i try to run it.

I am new to android so any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks a ton for your help and time.

Comment: The front camera initialization you are sharing here is not from my code. It's a part you have added, which may or may not be causing the error. I also guess you have only tried it on a simulator, which may or may not be misconfigured. I suggest you try the unmodified project on a real device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you are not getting the camera object right

this code will init the front camera properly
**part1**

```
cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
if (cameraId < 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No  camera found.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    mcamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
}
```

**part2**

```
 private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
      CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
      Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
        cameraId = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return cameraId;
  }
```

please try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Where do i insert this code? I will try right away. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: What type should cameraId be? I am getting an error there. Also for the second part which imports should i use? I imported what it recommend which changed it to Camera.CameraInfo. That ok?

Comment: Oh ok i see, i just needed to add the int in front of cameraId since it is getting the return value from findFrontFacingCamera. That fixed it that. Now for some weird reason it is just saying it can't cannot resolve symbol for mcamera after the else. Which makes no sense.

Comment: Ill update the new code to show you the changes i made to insure they are what you reoccmendd. Again huge thanks for all your help

Comment: Yes that was the reason! So there are almost no errors now. The last thing is the Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found"); for some reason could not find BEBUG_TAG after this all is good since there are no errors when i commented out that line

Comment: Great! All is fixed and there are no errors. I will try and run now. Quick question does the emulater for the nexus 5 api 23 allow me to use the front camera using my web cam or do i actually need a device to test?

Comment: Ok i will. I will have a device by tomorrow. I will let you know ASAP. If for some reason it has trouble is team view out of the question?

Comment: I very much appreciate it! I will get back to you. Have a great night!

Comment: IT worked!!!! Thank you very much! It does need an android device. The emulator will still cause the nullPointerException. Also if you don't mind marking the question up.I dont know why someone marked it down. A mark down stops me from being able to ask questions later.